# How can I create a matrix so I can access each number from the array like so $array[$key]

Tags: php, arrays, matrix

I am trying to create a multi-dimensional array from a text file so I can access each number. For example the first 7 would be $triangle[0][0] and the first 5 would be $triangle[0][1]. The code I've written so far is

```
<?php
$triangles = explode("\n", file_get_contents('18.txt'));
var_dump($triangles);
?>
```

This produced the following output. What do I need to change here? Thanks

```
array (size=15)
 0 => string '75' (length=3)
 1 => string '95 64' (length=6)
 2 => string '17 47 82' (length=9)
 3 => string '18 35 87 10' (length=12)
 4 => string '20 04 82 47 65' (length=15)
 5 => string '19 01 23 75 03 34' (length=18)
 6 => string '88 02 77 73 07 63 67' (length=21)
 7 => string '99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92' (length=24)
 8 => string '41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33' (length=27)
 9 => string '41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29' (length=30)
10 => string '53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14' (length=33)
11 => string '70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57' (length=36)
12 => string '91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48' (length=39)
13 => string '63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31' (length=42)
14 => string '04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23' (length=44)
```

Comment: What you're trying to do won't work. `00` and `01` are just the numbers `0` and `1` (leading zeroes just mean to parse it as octal). You should access it as `$triangles[0][0]` and `$triangles[0][1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to get the contents of the file into an array where each array element is a line from the file, then map [`str_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) over that array to separate each line into individual characters.

```
$triangles = array_map('str_split', file('18.txt',  FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES ));

echo $triangles[0][0];    // outputs 7
echo $triangles[0][1];    // outputs 5
```

---

If you don't want the spaces, you can use `str_replace` to remove them before splitting the line into individual characters.

```
$triangles = array_map(function($line) {
    return str_split(str_replace(' ', '', $line));
}, file('18.txt',  FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES ));
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But it outputs spaces for example $triangles[2][2] how do I get rid of the spaces?

Comment: @CalebOki I updated the answer with a way to eliminate the spaces.